# How can I escape Twig code to prevent it from being parsed?

Tags: templating, escaping

How do I escape Twig code to prevent it from being processed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **Escape single lines as strings:**

   ```
   {{ '{% set foo = "bar" %}' }}
   ```
2. **Use [`autoescape`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html) to escape multiple lines, optionally specifying a syntax (see docs):**

   ```
   {% autoescape %}
        {% if foo != "bar" %}
            {% set foo = "bar" %}
        {% endif %}
   {% endautoescape %}
   ```
3. **Use [`verbatim`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) to treat multiple lines as raw text**:

   ```
   {% verbatim %}
        {% if foo != "bar" %}
            {% set foo = "bar" %}
        {% endif %}   
   {% endverbatim %}
   ```

Comment: might want to also add the |raw filter here for completeness as the question does say "prevent it from being processed"?